# Should I allow viewing my website by entering the IP in url bar

Tags: apache

Should I allow viewing my website by entering the IP in url bar? that means that instead of writing site.com in the browser, I write the IP of the website. 
 Example:
 this IP 85.17.159.246 is not accessible if you put it in the browser bar. But the website hosted by it azlyrics.com is available.

Google on the hand allows viewing its website via direct IP, for example if you use 64.233.165.190 in your browser it will show Google's website.

Is it bad to allow that? Is it good? Why?
  In the past I've read that it is not a good idea to allow this, but now I really don't know how to search for this, as all the results on Google return with irrlevant pages.
  If it is not a good idea, how can I block it? (without blocking the website url, of course)

Answer (score 0):

We do have domain names for a reason, it brings several nice benefits as being able to move your site to a new IP but keeping the same domain name. Also when using domain names you can have multiple websites on a single IP.

Comment: yes, but are there any security issues if I allow this? and just in case, how can I block it?

Comment: There should be no security issues using ip only

Answer (score 0):

It's not bad. But an IP can only "host" one site. This works for Google, since they'd only be serving up google.com content anyways. But consider a shared server with (say) 50 different sites on it.

When you punch in `http://example.com`, your browser will hit example.com's IP and include a `Host: example.com` in the request's HTTP headers. That lets the server identify which of its sites you're requesting.

But if you hit the server's IP directly, there's no Host: header, and now Apache has no idea which of the sites you really want.

Comment: yes, indeed, I forgot to mention I use a dedicated IP. my questions rather refers to security issues, or, maybe even SEO issues - could this be seen as duplicate content? I know Google treats them differently